# Laptop/Tablet BatteryCycleCount for Determining its Health

Tags: c#

Please help me to get Laptop/Tablet "BatteryCycleCount" value. Based on this property we will determine the replacement of battery.
Below are some APIs, which i have found in my googling:

```
[DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
protected static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref Guid gClass, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strEnumerator, IntPtr hParent, uint nFlags);

[DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
protected static extern bool SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(IntPtr lpDeviceInfoSet, uint nDeviceInfoData, ref Guid gClass, uint nIndex, ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA oInterfaceData);

[DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
protected static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(IntPtr lpDeviceInfoSet, ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA oInterfaceData, ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA oDetailData, uint nDeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, ref uint nRequiredSize, IntPtr lpDeviceInfoData);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
protected static extern IntPtr CreateFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strName, uint nAccess, uint nShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurity, uint nCreationFlags, uint nAttributes, IntPtr lpTemplate);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool DeviceIoControl([In] SafeHandle hDevice, [In] int dwIoControlCode, [In] IntPtr lpInBuffer, [In] int nInBufferSize, [Out] IntPtr lpOutBuffer, [In] int nOutBufferSize, out int lpBytesReturned, [In] IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct use of the Windows API, you can request the performance counters in the category "BatteryStatus".

Edit :

The counters in the category "BatteryStatus" are multi instance : one per battery. On my laptop, I can write this C# code :

```
var counter = new PerformanceCounter("BatteryStatus", "RemainingCapacity", "ACPI\PNP0C0A\0_0", true);
var remainingCapacity = counter.NextValue();
```

You can view all the available counters in the category "BatteryStatus" with Performance Monitor ("perfmon" command).

Comment: What "category"? And how are you going to make this "request" without calling an API function?